# CS50 recover doesn't output any images

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on the recover program of the CS50 course. Here are the instructions:

> - Implement your program in a file called recover.c in a directory called recover.
> - Your program should accept exactly one command-line argument, the name of a forensic image from which to recover JPEGs.
> - If your program is not executed with exactly one command-line argument, it should remind the user of correct usage, and main should
>   return 1.
> - If the forensic image cannot be opened for reading, your program should inform the user as much, and main should return 1.
> - Your program, if it uses malloc, must not leak any memory.

I think my code is supposed to work, but it doesn't. In fact, it doesn't output any images at all! Here's the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * pFile = NULL;
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(512);
    char* filename = NULL;
    int filenumber = 0;

    //If user didn't print 2 items
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Open the file
    pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!pFile)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File cannot be opened\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int j=0;
    
    // checking the card by 512b chunks 
    //loop (i=0,  i++);
    while (pFile)
    {
        int i =0;
        i++;

        //k=fread (buffer, 512, i, *file);
        int k = fread(buffer, 512, i, pFile);
        
        // if 512 byte block is jpeg, make new jpeg file
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // if it's not the first file, we should close the last one
            if (filename != NULL)
            {
                fclose(pFile);
            }

            //sprintf
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", 2);

            //FILE = fopen (W) 
            pFile = fopen(filename, "w");

            // fwrite (buffer, 512, j, *file1)
            fwrite (buffer, 512, j, pFile);

            //j=j+1
            j = j + 1;
        }

        // if k<512 - end of the loop
        if (k < 512)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    free(buffer);
}
```

I don't understand it, but I see no new files or JPEGs pop-up in my files. When I try to double-click on the file, which is called card.raw, it doesn't let me open it.

Comment: I repeat my comment from your previous question: Proper indentation is important. Don't make it hard to read for us and, even more important, for yourself!

Comment: What do you mean? It's pretty easy to read in my opinion

Comment: You have no indentation of logical blocks at all in second half of your code. If you have to search for corresponding brackets because they are all at first column, it is not easy to read. You must **see** the logical blocks at first glance.

Comment: But I have comments everywhere which explains it. I'll try to make the comments more clear.

Comment: If your intention is to keep people away from reading your code, that's the way to go.

Comment: huh? why do comments keep people away from reading my code?

Comment: `//loop (i=0,  i++); while (pFile)` The comment is not related to the instruction in the next line but only a few lines below. That is more confusing than helping. What is `pFile`? Is your input file expected to change during runtime?

Comment: Not comment. Refusing to apply indentation distracts people. Especially after being told a few times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220034/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-lost-in-code).

Comment: @Lostincode your nickname is great. Poorly formatted code is hard to read, to debug and to maintain. For instance I get lost in poorly formatted code.

Comment: Please do not change your code after comments and answers were given. It makes them useless and confuses future readers. I will roll back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a load of problems. Running your code in a debugger should reveal most of them within a second.

Let's take a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * pFile = NULL;
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(512);
    char* filename = NULL;  <<==== You never allocate any memory for this. Use an array.
    int filenumber = 0;

    //If user didn't print 2 items
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Open the file
    pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!pFile)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File cannot be opened\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int j=0;
    
    // checking the card by 512b chunks 
    //loop (i=0,  i++);   <<== No information provided by this comment.
    while (pFile)       <<== pFile is your input file. This should never change. ???
    {
        int i =0;
        i++;

        //k=fread (buffer, 512, i, *file);    <<== Useless comment. Nearly same as code below but causes compiler error
        int k = fread(buffer, 512, i, pFile); <<== i is always 1 and must be 1. Don't use variable.
                                              <<== BTW: You should check k **before** using the buffer.


        // if 512 byte block is jpeg, make new jpeg file
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // if it's not the first file, we should close the last one
            if (filename != NULL)
            {
                fclose(pFile);  <<== Yikes!!! This is your input file.
            }

            //sprintf  <<== Yes, that's obvious. Useless comment.
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", 2);  <<== Yikes!! You never allocate memory. NULL pointer!!
                                               <<== Why do you always print 2? you have a counter.

            //FILE = fopen (W)  <<== Again no useful information in comment
            pFile = fopen(filename, "w");  <<== Feed NULL into fopen and kill pFile.

            // fwrite (buffer, 512, j, *file1)  <<== you know what I mean...
            fwrite (buffer, 512, j, pFile);  <<== You only have 1 buffer, why write j blocks?

            //j=j+1  <<== obvious
            j = j + 1;
        }

        // if k<512 - end of the loop
        if (k < 512)   <<== fread returns number of elements, i.e. 1, not number of bytes.
        {
            << you return without
               - closing files
               - freeing buffer
            return 0;
        }
   <<== Now you go back to top of the loop and want to read next block from your raw file but pFile was killed in the loop.

    }
    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this part: 'pFile = fopen(filename, "w");  <<== Feed NULL into fopen and kill pFile.' and this part: '<<== BTW: You should check k **before** using the buffer.' Also this: ' <<== You only have 1 buffer, why write j blocks?' I Also don't understand the '<<== Yikes!!! This is your input file.' part. If I shouldn't put pFile there, what should I put?

Comment: If you start reading from the top, you should find that you never allocate any memory for `filename` and it is still `NULL` when you put it into `fopen`.

Comment: Why do you think, you can write `j` blocks of 512 bytes at once if you only have a buffer of 512 bytes? Why should the size increase (you do `j=j+1` after each block) all the time?

Comment: What do you mean by: "allocate any memory for filename"? What should I do instead?

Comment: Sorry to say that. But you should start over again and look into your text book about pointers. You must use `malloc` to get some memory where the pointer can point to. Or you could simply use an array `char filename[10];` instead of a pointer.

Comment: The "kill pFile" comment means that you override the previous content of `pFile` which is still required to read more blocks from your raw file. If you want to handle 2 files, use 2 `FILE*` variables.

Comment: Lets continue talking in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220134/discussion-between-lost-in-code-and-gerhardh).